# How to determine if using MVC4 vs MVC5 vs MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I keep seeing articles about MVC6, but I'm a bit confused... MVC5 isn't even released, is it?  I have in my VS2015 an option to download and use the RC 1 of MVC5, which I haven't done because until it's released, we're not using it one our production apps.  But why are there so many articles and questions about converting to MVC6?  SHouldn't I be worried about converting to MVC5 whenever (if) it gets released?

Supposedly SO considers this to be a question of opinion, so here is a re-worded question:

When I create a new MVC app in VS2015, the shown templates are MVC with a little 4 in the top right corner of the icon. Is this MVC4 or MVC5? I've created lots of projects using that icon, and none of them include a startup.cs, they're all global.asax... I thought MVC5 was supposed to be built on OWIN and uses a Startup.cs? If this is indeed MVC5, what does that little 4 represent? How does one actually know and determine what version of anything they're using?

Comment: First Google hit for "ASP.NET MVC 5": [ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5). It's production-ready.

Comment: "VS2015 an option to download and use the RC 1 of MVC5" that option is for *ASP.NET* 5, not MVC 5.

Comment: When I create a new MVC app, the shown templates are MVC with a little 4 in the top right corner of the icon.  Is this MVC4 or MVC5? I've created lots of projects using that icon, and none of them include a startup.cs, they're all global.asax... I thought MVC5 was supposed to be built on OWIN and uses a Startup.cs?  If this is indeed MVC5, what does that little 4 represent?  How does one actually know and determine what version of anything they're using?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MVC5 has been out for quite some time. [Since 2013](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.0.0).

The ASP.NET version number and the MVC version number are not always in sync. What Visual Studio is offering to download is *ASP.NET* 5, not MVC 5. MVC 6 runs on top of ASP.NET 5, which has been renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0.